# How to store data of mongodb through get request in local storage as an array

Tags: angular, mongodb, api, get, local-storage

I have a service that sends a get request to fetch data from my mongodb collection and i want to store that incoming data into the localstorage as an array also.

**API.SERVICE.TS**

```
getStorageLocationsList(){
    this.setHeader();
    return this.http.get(this.localURL + 'storagelocation/view' + '?userplant=' + this.userplant , {headers:this.appHeader});
  }
```

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
this._api.getStorageLocationsList().subscribe(res => {
      this.storagelocationsList = res as Event[];
      //console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
//I want some more code here to store the data in res to the localstorage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this._api.getStorageLocationsList().subscribe(res => {
      this.storagelocationsList = res as Event[];
      //console.log(res);
      let storagelocationsList = ['A', 'B']; // suppose this is your api response
      localStorage.setItem('locationList', JSON.stringify(storagelocationsList));  
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

> For Fetch : `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locationList'));`

For more operations of localStorage check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)